# bin directory and PATH

Tags: windows, path

I'm beginner in programming. Can somebody please explain (by simple words) what do I have inside the bin directory of program?

What is this `PATH` environment variable of windows, how does it work (please don't think that I don't know how to use Google, I just want to understand it more clearly)?

Comment: The concept of a "bin" directory is more commonly used on *nix systems, not on Windows.  Do you know what the PATH environment variable is used for?  What exactly are you looking to clarify?

Comment: @James McNellis: I read some information, but a little bit difficult to understand, so can You explain?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @Paul R - why? It's programming related in that you need to know how to organise your dlls so your program works.

Comment: @ChrisF: to me it just seems to be a question about `PATH` on Windows, which is more related to how a particular OS works rather than anything specifically programming-related.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You usually put all the binary files for a program in the bin directory. This would be the executable itself and any dlls (dynamic link libraries) that the program uses.

This isn't essential as Windows use the PATH environment variable to look for dlls your program needs. This is a list of folders that Windows searches, in order, when it can't find a dll (say) in the current directory.

So if you want to have a dll used by more than one program you could put it in a location already on the PATH or add a new folder to the PATH.

Comment: first of all, thanks for answer, secondly, so PATH I need only for dll (I mean for windows to know where it can find some library)?

Comment: @wantSTUDY - PATH is used for other things as well - for example if you just type the name of an exe from the command prompt Windows uses the PATH to search for it if it's not in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

The /bin directory contains the essential user binaries (programs) that must be present when the system is mounted in single-user mode. Applications such as Firefox are stored in /usr/bin, while important system programs and utilities such as the bash shell are located in /bin. The /usr directory may be stored on another partition — placing these files in the /bin directory ensures the system will have these important utilities even if no other file systems are mounted. The /sbin directory is similar — it contains essential system administration binaries.