# why do we add bin directory to the path inside Environment Variables?

Tags: java, opencv, path, environment, bin

Often times I found myself editing Path in Environment Variables for the purpose of installation some new library files into the Operating System for e.g adding Java jdk bin or OpenCv Bin into the Path inside Environment Variables.

My question is what benefit does this bring to the operating system and how does it help  ; other than the fact that I am able to compile the java files through command prompt after this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bin directory and PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224606/bin-directory-and-path)

Comment: This is a strange question... you state what the path environment variable is useful for, and then you ask what benefit it brings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add something to your system path it could be more visible for applications that need to have access to it. It acts like a bridge between application and it's requirements. It's a common way for many applications (ex. OpenCV or JDK) to have access to their modules and libraries through this system variables. If you don't set this variables they have no choice where to search for their requirements!

Comment: I could not really understand what you meant by bridge? a bridge between Operating system and the Application(ex: OpenCV or JDK)? In simple words is it appropriate to say that setting the variables points to the necessary files which are needed for application to run; so when the application does run.. it searches where the required files are.. goes to take help from the environment variables.. than the environment variables redirects the application to the required files.. and than the application smoothly runs.. –

Comment: Yes! exactly and even maybe it could not run at all without this environment variables help.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my concept.